# Is this punctuation wrong or just stilted?

Tags: punctuation

I tend to over-punctuate because I don't have a clue (or I use speech as an guideline)

Are the commas wrong or just awkward in the sentence below?

*It was controversial, in part, because of the lying. . .*

Comment: Not related to the comma - but sometimes you want to show graphically "pauses" or "hesitations" that occur in the speech, and "..." is a good way to do this IMO. For example, "It was... *controversial*, in part because of the... lack of honesty." In that example, the speaker is obviously making more effort to choose words for "controvesial" and "lack of honesty". This happens often in spoken dialogue but is rarely reflected orthographically.

Comment: I'm wondering if commas or dashes (i.e., `It was controversial -- in part -- because of the lying. . .`) are more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly not *wrong*.  Setting "in part" off with commas like that make it seem parenthetical.  If you are intending to acknowledge that the explanation is partial without discussing other explanations, the commas strike me as correct, almost obligatory.

So:

> It was controversial, in part, because of the lying.

*but*

> It was controversial in part because of the lying but mostly because
>   of his sheer brazenness.

*and even*

> It was controversial, in part because of the lying, but mostly we objected to the dishonesty.

Also, the exact placement of "in part" makes the sentence ambiguous.  I would prefer either

> It was in part controversial because of the lying.

(that is, it was partly controversial) or

> It was controversial because, in part, of the lying.

(that is, it was controversial and the lying was part of the reason).

If you find that *because, in part,* to be less than euphonious, consider

> It was controversial partly because of the lying.

Since the other possibility would necessarily be expressed as "It was partly controversial because of the lying", this order is not ambiguous.

Comment: In your example with "but" – that was my initial formulation of the sentence: no commas at all but then I thought I had to put in commas because I heard the pause in my head   xxxxx xx xxxxxxx - like a breath – so  with'but' plus commas. Your last example sounds 'off' to my ear.

Comment: Whatever you set off in commas will be read as tangential to the main point.  See my changes.  *And:* Three tomatoes are walking down the street, Papa Tomato, Mama Tomato, and little Baby Tomato. Baby Tomato starts lagging behind. Papa Tomato gets angry, goes over to Baby Tomato, and *smooshes him* and says, "Catch up!"

Comment: `euphonious` - I like it. I am going to rename my daughter *Euphonia* (I wonder if she find it pleasing to the ear . . .). Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @TOMATO What I imagine an average day is like at your house: "Huh. That's a nice word..." (calling) "Honey! Can you bring your birth certificate in here?" ... "Yes, **again**. Someone just used the word 'mellifluous' in this internet conversation and I want that to be your name, now." ... "Hey- HEY! Don't you sass me, Tourmaline! So get in here- and tell [Tarquin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xblh12XgQ4o) and Propentine that dinner'll be ready in an hour."